# Does Ubuntu contain its own picture/video viewer/player?

Tags: video, photo-management

A photo of a photo among photos and videos on a homemade disc did not display on my Dell Inspiron B130, but it was displayed on a computer with the Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Ubuntu comes with the [Shotwell](http://yorba.org/shotwell/) photo program and the [Totem video player](http://projects.gnome.org/totem/) by default.